# Minecraft bot error using mineflayer for node JS

Tags: node.js, minecraft

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?

"WARNING : unknown transaction confirmation for window 0, action 1432 and accepted false"

for this code:

```
var mineflayer = require('mineflayer')
 
var bot = mineflayer.createBot({
  host: 'SERVER', // optional
  port: 25565,      // optional
  username: 'USERNAME',
  version: '1.16.1'
})

bot.on("login", async => {
    console.log("Ingame Bot Online")
   // bot.chat("Hello")
})

function Login(arg) {
  bot.chat("/login PASSWORD")
}

setTimeout(Login, 3500);
```